# Similarity of two sets of scatter data

Tags: normal-distribution, gaussian-mixture-distribution, similarities

I am currently working on a project where I have a dataset of scatter-points in space. What I am doing is that I fit Gaussian Mixture Models (GMM) on the data set and use the model to sample 'artificial' data points for simulation purposes. What I would like to do now is find a metric to see how well the GMM reproduces the original data. For this purpose, I thought about comparing the original scatter-data with the artificial data. Is there some sort of 'similarity' measure between two data sets?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi and Welcome to CV! What is the dimension of your data?

Comment: Hi! It is 3-D, but I might try a version with 2-D data as well.